# What does the cluster point property mean?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology

Let $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function. We say that $y$ is a cluster point of function $f$ at $x$ if for every open set $U$ with $y\in U$ we have $$\bigg(f^{-1}(U)\cap (x-r,x+r)\bigg)-\{x\}\neq\emptyset$$ for every $r>0.$ I know this definition. I was wondering what it means to say that $f$ has the cluster point property. Any help will be appreciated greatly

Comment: @OliverDiaz, I know this is equivalent for saying $y$ is a cluster point of $f$ at $x.$ My question was what does it mean $f$ has cluster point property ?does it mean has cluster point at any point.

Comment: It means that $(x,y)$ is a cluster pint (in the sense of topology) of the graph of $f$, $\operatorname{graph}(f)=\{(x,f(x))\}$. In functional analysis, the the continuity of a linear map can be reduced to closure properties of its graph. I think that is hy they introduce the concept you are referring to.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, Thank you so much. This still not answer my question. because I do not know Is it  mean it any point

Comment: If you give some context, perhaps someone will be able to assist you.

Comment: It likely means that *"$f$ has the cluster point property at $y$ if ...*. In which case it would mean that $(x,y)$ is in the closure of the graph of $f$.  I don't think it would be vary meaningful to talk about a "global" cluster point property; one would get a function whose graph is dense in $X\times Y $ (in your case $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ unless of course you are studying curves that fillip the whole space or things of that sort.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, Thanks again. Even me I just found it and I thought there is clear definition for it but it seems not. Since it seems to me you have good understanding for cluster point. I know cluster point for sequence I have picture what is does it mean. Cluster point of function at point . I am not quit sure what exactly mean I just started the terms two last week and I even did not find at any books as cluster point of function. what is the relation between cluster point and density of the graph. It would be nice if you cloud explain that to me

Comment: @OliverDiaz, In my last comment. I was asking in general how one can  have clear picture  a cluster point of function at point.

Comment: I just told you, you can see that by looking at the graph of the function. For example, if you look at the graph of say, $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ then $1$ and $0$ are cluster points of $f$ at say $x=0$ (in fact at any $x\in\mathbb{R}$) ) that is, the points $(x,0)$ and $(x,1)$ are cluster points of the graph of $f$.